# Checking if coroutine is done then calling a function once it is done

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 bool isAnimationDone = false;   
 void AnimalSounds(){
    clear ();
    currentAnimation = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Animals/AnimalIntro", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
    StartCoroutine (Animations());

   if(isAnimationDone = true){
      doThis();
 }


}

IEnumerator Animations(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
    Destroy (currentAnimation);
    isAnimationDone = true;
    yield break;
}
```

I'm currently working with coroutines, but I'm having a hard time dealing with them. I just want to delay my animations for a few seconds then call a function once it is destroyed.

Comment: Note that `yield break` at the end of an iterator block is redundant.  Reaching the end of the method already ends the iterator.

Comment: @Servy i already saw that but i cant understand the logic on that answer.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?   You know how to make a function a co-routine, given that you've already made one.  So make `AnimalSounds` a coroutine.  What problems are you having doing that?